# Request app links in android - no request ids

Tags: android, facebook

I've set up a basic application, using "Send Requests" and "Handle Request App Links" docs as a reference.

Now when I check only "Facebook login" in my app settings, request app links don't work at all - facebook app gets into infinite "wait while I'm loading something" state.

When I check both "Facebook login" and "Deep linking", request app links do work - however, no request ids are being sent to my app. In fact, getIntent().getData() returns only:
http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=[app id]

Here's my code for sending request:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", invite_message);
WebDialog requestsDialog = (
    new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(this,
        Session.getActiveSession(), params)).setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {
                on_invite_request_complete(values, error);
            }

        }).build();
requestsDialog.show();
```

Any suggestions, except for double-checking app settings of Facebook? 
Or is there something really easy to miss in these settigs?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind - checking out "Knowing issues" page revealed that Facebook is having issues with notifications on Android since Marh, 28th.